# Using MySQL stored procedure in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I can not find what is the error in this code. According to me it's good and hope to execute properly but I am getting an error:

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.7.11]
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ViewBatchByID' at line 1

My code Is

```
string Message = null;

OdbcCommand Cmd = new OdbcCommand();
Cmd.Connection = Connection.con;
Cmd.CommandText = "ViewBatchByID";
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", 1);

try
{
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   Message = ex.Message.ToString();
}
```

HERE `ViewBatchByID` is my stored procedure and it's working fine from server.

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: I used both "command.Parameters.Add()" or "command.Parameters.AddWithValue()"  &  Parameter Direction also  But i am getting same Error.

Comment: The parameter name in actual procedure is @p0 ?

Comment: I use It Also but i get an Error or Parameter Null Value
OdbcCommand  cmd=("{call  ViewBatchByID (?)}",Connection.con);

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I had the same problem.  After a little more research and some trial and error, I was able to resolve it as follows.

First, the command text needs to be changed for MySQL.  Microsoft SQL Server only requires the stored procedure name in the command text, but for MySQL you need to specify the full command to execute.  So, for example, your stored procedure with one parameter would need to be set as follows:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "{call ViewBatchByID(?)}";
```

Note that if the stored procedure has more than one parameter, you must enter a question mark for each parameter, with a comma between each.  So if your stored procedure required two parameters, it would need to be set as follows:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "{call ViewBatchByID(?,?)}";
```

In addition, MySQL doesn't use the @ sign to denote parameters in a stored procedure.  Your parameter should be added as follows:

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("firstParam", firstValue));
```

So, a solution to the original code snippet may appear like this:

```
string Message = null;

try
{
    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand("{call ViewBatchByID(?)}", Connection.con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("p0", 1));
        
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Message = ex.Message.ToString();
}
```

This assumes from the original code snippet that the connection is already open and referenced from the object "Connection.con".

Answer (score -1):

Check the connection settings for the server. Is the `Database` set?

`Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database=AdventureWorks;`

Comment: I set it in web config and working with all other query